# Gradle Application Plugin with Logback

Tags: java, gradle, logback

I am using the Gradle Application Plugin to generate a bundle for my Java application.  I would like to write logs files into a directory, `logs`, at the root of the installed application, regardless of where the startup script is launched from.  I'm using Logback to do the logging.  The the problem I have is that if I specify a relative path for the logs, the directory ends up wherever the application is launched from.

For now, the solution I have come up with is as follows.  Firstly, I force Gradle to export the application directory variable `$APP_HOME`:

```
startScripts {
    doLast {
        unixScript.text = unixScript.text
                .replaceAll('(?m)^APP_HOME=', 'export APP_HOME=')
    }
}
```

Then in the Logback configuration I use the variable:

```
<file>${APP_HOME:-.}/logs/system.log</file>
```

I've given this a default value of a dot so that I can still run the application from my IDE where the variable won't be set.

This seems to work but its a bit of a hack and its only a solution of Unix/Linux.

So does anyone have a suggestion for a better way of working with the Gradle Application Plugin and logging to the directory in which the application is installed?

Comment: I finally got a chance to try this on Windows and it works as well there.  There is no need to add anything more to the `startScripts` section as the generated batch file contains a `set` command that appears to work like `export` on Unix.